# How many almonds a day can cause toxicity for vitE?

Tags: vitamins

Vit E in high doses is dangerous for tissue. How many almonds a day taken regularly can cause this?

RDA
Males : 10mg/day
Females : 8mg/day
Pregnancy : 10mg/day
Lactation : 12mg/day

15 mg = 33IU for vit E

Requirement increase for higher intake of pufa

Pharmacological dose: 200-400 IU/day

Comment: Almonds contain  hydrocyanic acid, apparently [as much as 25 mg/kg (8mg/kg standard deviation)](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2013/610648/). However, it would take at least 2 kg of almonds (roughly 1650 kernels) to reach a lethal dose, which is highly unlikely to be digested unintentionally. You may die before vit e toxicity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can eat bags and bags of almonds every day for years and not be in any risk of vitamin E toxicity. There are many, *many* cases of adults consuming 500+ mg of Vitamin E every day, for years on end, with no signs of harm.

In general though, the max daily recommended value of vitamin E consumption is 1000mg. One cup of almonds (100g, or ~100 kernels) contains a little under 30mg of vitamin E. That being said, you can consume over 30 cups of almonds in one day before reaching the daily recommended limit.

You would have to eat tens of hundreds of thousands of almonds for there to be any kind of health concern.. at which point, you would probably suffer from other conditions than vitamin E toxicity.

You (should) have nothing to worry about.

---

EDIT: Here are a couple sources...

This page has everything about recommended limits, research that has been done, tables with daily limit values, etc. 
[US Department of Health and Human Services - National Institutes of Health](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminE-HealthProfessional/#h7)

> Research has not found any adverse effects from consuming vitamin E in food.

This page contains basic nutritional facts for almonds. A 95g serving is about 90 whole kernel almonds. [Nuts, Almonds - Nutrition Facts](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3085/2)

> Serving size 95 g ... Vitamin E (Alpha Tocopherol) 24.9 mg